# Download doc from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

for some reason after I click the url to download, it happen to view the file on my browser which results it massive symbols and random letters. Is there any way to get it to download rather than viewing it on browser? I'm really new to programming, you guidance would really be helpful. Thank you.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("tuitioncentre");

if(isset($_GET['id'])) { // if id is set then get the file with the id from database

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM files WHERE id = $id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

list($name, $type, $size, $content) =

mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length: $size");

header("Content-type: $type");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

echo $content; exit;

}

?>



<?php

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM files";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)

{

echo "Database is empty";

}

else

{

while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

?>

<a href="download2.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>

<?php

}

}
```

?>

This is example of the output.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx6XR.png

Comment: Seems like you have the incorrect type being set, what is it from your database? As well for the love of god don't use the mysql_* functions, switch to PDO.

Comment: The type from my database is application/msword.

Comment: in your browser what are the response headers? I'm asking this because I suspect you have some output before thus the headers are ignored and the output gets sent to the browser. The output could be as simple as a single space.

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at line 145) Line 145 is header("Content-length: $size");

Comment: comment out your header statements and `echo $content;` what's left in your browser after it's all said and done?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: @Augwa When I clicked on the link, it just goes to localhost/tuitioncentre/download2?id=6. No errors.

Comment: yes but if you try to select the content there's probably a space or something. Somewhere in your code you're echoing out a space or other character (intentionally or otherwise). If you post your entire code block it'll be very easy to spot. If you have a space at the top of your file it will also cause problems.